# How can I add ID from logged session to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a order form. I want to add the information of the form in the table order in my database. But I want to add the ID from the logged session in that table of the database but I don't know how.

This is my php code:

```
<?php

   session_start();
   include 'conexion.php';

   $numero = $_POST["numero"];
   $fechac = $_POST["fechacreacion"];
   $fechav = $_POST["fechavencimiento"];
   $con = $_POST["condiciones"];
   $sub = $_POST["subtotal"];
   $iva = $_POST["iva"];
   $total = $_POST["total"];
   $observaciones = $_POST["observaciones"];
   $idus = session_id();
   $pnum = $_POST["pnum"];

   $insertar ="INSERT INTO pedido(numero,fechaCreacion,fechaVencimiento,condiciones,subtotal,iva,total,observaciones,Usuario_idUsuario,Proveedor_numeroIdent)VALUES ('$numero','$fechac','$fechav','$con','$sub','$iva','$total','$observaciones','$idus','$pnum')";

   $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);

   if (!$resultado) {
    echo mysqli_error($conexion);
   } else {
      echo 'Se ha llenado el formulario con exito';
   }

   mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

And this is the code of the form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang ="es">
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title> Pedido</title>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href = "css/estilos_pedido.css">
</head>
  <body>
   <h1><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="" class="logo"></h1>
    <form action ="Pedido.php" method ="post" class= "form-register">
        <h2 class = "form__titulo"> Pedido</h2>
        <div class = "contenedor-inputs">
            <input type ="number" name ="numero" placeholder ="Numero" class = "input-48"  required> 
            <input type ="date" name ="fechacreacion" placeholder ="Fecha creacion" class = "input-48" required> 
            <input type ="date" name ="fechavencimiento" placeholder ="Fecha vencimiento" class = "input-48" required> 
            <input type ="text" name ="condiciones" placeholder ="Condiciones" class = "input-48" required> 
            <input type ="number" name ="subtotal" placeholder ="Subtotal" class = "input-48" required> 
            <input type ="number" name ="iva" placeholder ="IVA" class = "input-48" required> 
            <input type ="number" name ="total" placeholder ="Total" class = "input-100" required > 
            <input type ="text" name ="observaciones" placeholder ="Observaciones" class = "input-100" required >    
            <input type ="text" name ="pnum" placeholder ="numeroidentificacion del proveedor" class = "input-100" required >    
            <input type ="submit" value ="enviar pedido" class = "btn-enviar">
        <p> </p>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the code I have this error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`pedido`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Pedido_Usuario1` FOREIGN KEY (`Usuario_idUsuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`idUsuario`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I don't know it it's my code or another thing.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You are already storing the session data to `$idus`, and inserting it to the database. What's the problem?

Comment: Yeah, but it's the correct form to add the id for the actual sessión? When I send the form I have this error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails. And that made me think that it was not the right way to do it.